# Fetch data subset from gmond

Tags: monitoring, rrdtool, ganglia

This is in the context of a small data-center setup where the number of servers to be monitored are only in double-digits and may grow only slowly to few hundreds (if at all). I am a ganglia newbie and have just completed setting up a small ganglia test bed (and have been reading and playing with it). The couple of things I realise -

- gmetad supports interactive queries on port 8652 using which I can get metric data *subsets*  - say data of particular metric family in a specific cluster
- gmond seems to always return the whole dump of data for all metrics from all nodes in a cluster (on doing 'netcat host 8649')

In my setup, I dont want to use gmetad or RRD. I want to directly fetch data from the multiple gmond clusters and store it in a single data-store. There are couple of reasons to not use gmetad and RRD -

- I dont want multiple data-stores in the whole setup. I can have one dedicated machine to fetch data from the multiple, few clusters and store them
- I dont plan to use gweb as the data front end. The data from ganglia will be fed into a different monitoring tool altogether. With this setup, I want to eliminate the latency that another layer of gmetad could add. That is, gmetad polls say every minute and my management tool polls gmetad every minute will add 2 minutes delay which I feel is unnecessary for a relatively small/medium sized setup

There are couple of problems in the approach for which I need help -

- I cannot get filtered data from gmond. Is there some plugin that can help me fetch individual metric/metric-group information from gmond (since different metrics are collected in different intervals)
- gmond output is very verbose text. Is there some other (hopefully binary) format that I can configure for export?
- Is my idea of eliminating gmetad/RRD completely a very bad idea? Has anyone tried this approach before? What should I be careful of, in doing so from a data collection standpoint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think, my answer to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675209/how-to-read-ganglia-information-from-other-application/26774475#26774475 , answers to your question as well. Take a look. Upvote the answer, if you think that is the one you are looking for. Let me know, if you need anything else.

Comment: thats one heck of an answer to a question! thanks for sharing!!