# Understanding XDR specification to create a *.x file

Tags: c, rpc, xdr, sunrpc

I have been looking through several websites on the Internet and actually wanted to know how do we write specification in a ***.x*** file to generate equivalent functions in **.c** file for RPC. Every site I visited suggested to use following kind of specification in ***.x** file:

```
program ADD_PROG { 
    version ADD_VERS { 
        int ADD(intpair) = 1; 
    } = 1; 
} = 0x23451111;
```

So, to understand practically, I obtained [gm_protocol.x](https://github.com/fastly/ganglia/blob/master/lib/gm_protocol.x) from an open-source project known as ganglia and generated equivalent C source code ([gm_protocol_xdr.c](https://github.com/simplegeo/ganglia/blob/master/lib/gm_protocol_xdr.c)) and C header file ([gm_protocol.h](https://github.com/simplegeo/ganglia/blob/master/lib/gm_protocol.h)) using rpcgen.

```
[rohit@ganglia-server rpc]$ rpcgen -C gm_protocol.x 
[rohit@ganglia-server rpc]$ 
[rohit@ganglia-server rpc]$ ll
total 24
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rohit rohit 5786 Oct 28 17:52 gm_protocol.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rohit rohit 3485 Oct 28 15:04 gm_protocol.x
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rohit rohit 8213 Oct 28 17:52 gm_protocol_xdr.c
```

To my surprise, from what I have learned and understood, gm_protocol.x doesn't contain any such RPC specifications shown as code above but still it can generate too many functions in the file gm_protocol_xdr.c.

It is pretty much sure that I am not able to understand the XDR specifications because either I have consulted wrong sources or they are outdated. I could not find any tutorial which could explain the way to generate functions (Although I have found specifications to generate struct, enum, union, etc).

Please help to learn these specifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, from .x file you generate three 'groups' of code: message xdr encoder/decoder functions, client stub and server stub ( well, you can do it by hand as well, but it's too much work to get it right ). Run rpcgen with -a option too generate client, server sthus and an example implementation. Try to use a simple example first:

```
program STRLEN {
  version STRLENVERS {
    int strlen(string) = 1;
  } = 1;
} = 117;
```

The specification `program` is a part of RPCL but XDR language. If one puts above specifications in a **test.x** file and run it using `rpcgen -C test.x`, then he/she would just get

> test.h,
>   test_svc.c,
>   test_clnt.c

If one doesn't need any server or client stubs and just need encoder and decoder functions of XDR then every specifications such as enum, struct, union, etc in the file **gm_protocol.x** would be generated into their equivalent C based declarations in **gm_protocol.h** and their corresponding XDR encoder and decoder functions would be generated in **gm_protocol_xdr.c**, which is the case specified in the question.

Running `rpcgen -a gm_protocol.x` would generate **gm_protocol_svc.c** and **gm_protocol_clnt.c** without any functions.

Below are some XDR specifications:

[image]

Check the old SUN docu http://www.shrubbery.net/solaris9ab/SUNWdev/ONCDG/toc.html

Comment: The link seems to be useful but this doesn't answer my question. My question is **gm_protocol.x** doesn't contain any specification as `program STLEN {` but still rpcgen can create **gm_protocol_xdr.c** file which contain functions.
According to "Unix Network Programming Vol 2 by Richard Stevens":
**The RPC specification (RFC 1831) says that the RPC language, sometimes called RPCL, is identical to the XDR language (which is defined in RFC 1832), except for the addition of a program definition (which describes the program, versions, and procedures).**
So, How are these functions created here?

Comment: rpcgen will generate an encoder/decoder function for any struct and enum defined in the .x file.The XDR encoded message is an array of bytes and you need to convert them into corresponding types.

Comment: This was what I thought earlier. So, this means that there is no need of putting `program STRLEN {` in the **.x** file to generate encoder/decoder functions. +1 for this confirmation. I'd edit your answer and add what makes the answer as complete. Thanks.