# How to use generated XDR structures from .x file (memory allocation)

Tags: c, xdr

I would please like some help with this case.

I need to send *one XDR message*, that it's composed by *2 files* (**switch case == OK**).

Assuming I have in my code a `message` object called `response`:

```
message response;
```

If I had to only send one file in a message, I would do:

```
response.message_u.fdata.last_mod_time         = last_modification;
response.message_u.fdata.contents.contents_len = file_size;
response.message_u.fdata.contents.contents_val = buffer;
```

With buffer being:

```
buffer = malloc(file_size * sizeof(char));
```

Now, I understand that `struct file fdata<2>;` it's a variable size array (2 is the max length) and that I would have them index as `something[0]` and `something[1]`.

Also I know I need to allocate memory, but I do not know how to do this in this case with multiple files.

Do I need to do one single malloc for everything I need to send? Something like this:

```
response.message_u.fdata.fdata_val = malloc ( (file_size1 * sizeof(char)) + (file_size2 * sizeof(char)) + (2 * sizeof(uint32_t)));
```

`(2 * sizeof(uint32_t))`: one *last_mod_time* for each file to send

And the other question how to I refer to each file structure:

```
response.message_u.fdata[0]                        //?
response.message_u.fdata.last_mod_time[0]          //?
response.message_u.fdata[0].last_mod_time          //?
response.message_u.fdata.contents.contents_len[0]  //?
response.message_u.fdata.contents.contents_val[0]  //?
```

The .x file:

```
enum tagtype {
    GET  = 0,
    OK   = 1,
    QUIT = 2,
    ERR  = 3
};

struct file {
    opaque contents<>;
    unsigned int last_mod_time;
};

typedef string filename<256>;

union message switch (tagtype tag) {
    case GET:
        filename filenamedata<2>;
    case OK:
        struct file fdata<2>;
    case QUIT:
        void;
    case ERR:
        void;
};
```

The types.c (generated with rpcgen):

```
#include "xdr_types.h"

bool_t
xdr_tagtype (XDR *xdrs, tagtype *objp)
{
    register int32_t *buf;

    if (!xdr_enum (xdrs, (enum_t *) objp))
         return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}

bool_t
xdr_file (XDR *xdrs, file *objp)
{
    register int32_t *buf;

    if (!xdr_bytes (xdrs, (char **)&objp->contents.contents_val, (u_int *) &objp->contents.contents_len, ~0))
        return FALSE;
    if (!xdr_u_int (xdrs, &objp->last_mod_time))
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}


bool_t
xdr_filename (XDR *xdrs, filename *objp)
{
    register int32_t *buf;

    if (!xdr_string (xdrs, objp, 256))
         return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}

bool_t
xdr_message (XDR *xdrs, message *objp)
{
     register int32_t *buf;

     if (!xdr_tagtype (xdrs, &objp->tag))
         return FALSE;

    switch (objp->tag) {
        case GET:
            if (!xdr_array (xdrs, (char **)&objp->message_u.filenamedata.filenamedata_val, (u_int *) &objp->message_u.filenamedata.filenamedata_len, 10,
            sizeof (filename), (xdrproc_t) xdr_filename))
            return FALSE;
            break;
        case OK:
            if (!xdr_array (xdrs, (char **)&objp->message_u.fdata.fdata_val, (u_int *) &objp->message_u.fdata.fdata_len, 10, sizeof (file), (xdrproc_t) xdr_file))
             return FALSE;
            break;
        case QUIT:
            break;
        case ERR:
            break;
        default:
            return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Thank you for reading this, and trying to understand this. I really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the problem you're having? What is the question? Is it only about the `malloc` thing? Something else? Something more?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hello, it's really about how to fill the response mesage. How to put the data:  something[0]=data and something[1]=data, but I dont know to do that. As I said in the post, I only know how to do it with one, not 2.

Comment: @wildplasser: No, but it's the language that rpcgen needs to generate the filter functions (`xdr_typename()`) for the usage of XDR as the OP cleary said. For more information about [the .x file see here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26625494/8051589).

Comment: @AndreKampling Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: You can't design an XDR format for a file of unknown length. You will just have to keep sending `xdr_arrays` of `char`, probably ending with one of zero length.

Comment: @EJP: May I get you wrong but sure the OP can and already does it: `opaque contents<>;`. His generated filter functions will handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question it is easier to take a look at the types: `tagtype`, `file`, `filename` and `message` that rpcgen generates from your .x file. They are located in your `xdr_types.h` which you didn't include in your question so I used rpcgen with your .x file. The important ones are `file` and `message`:

```
...

struct file {
   struct {
      u_int contents_len;
      char *contents_val;
   } contents;
   u_int last_mod_time;
};
typedef struct file file;

typedef char *filename;

struct message {
   tagtype tag;
   union {
      struct {
         u_int filenamedata_len;
         filename *filenamedata_val;
      } filenamedata;
      struct {
         u_int fdata_len;
         struct file *fdata_val;
      } fdata;
   } message_u;
};
typedef struct message message;

...
```

To answer your 2 questions:

> If I had to only send one file in a message, I would do:
>
> ```
> response.message_u.fdata.last_mod_time         = last_modification;
> response.message_u.fdata.contents.contents_len = file_size;
> response.message_u.fdata.contents.contents_val = buffer;
> ```
>
> With buffer being:
>
> ```
> buffer = malloc(file_size * sizeof(char));
> ```

and

> And the other question how to I refer to each file structure:
>
> ```
> response.message_u.fdata[0]                        //?
> response.message_u.fdata.last_mod_time[0]          //?
> response.message_u.fdata[0].last_mod_time          //?
> response.message_u.fdata.contents.contents_len[0]  //?
> response.message_u.fdata.contents.contents_val[0]  //?
> ```

No, the part after `response.message_u.fdata.` is wrong. It can either be:

```
response.message_u.fdata.fdata_len
```

or

```
response.message_u.fdata.fdata_val
```

and you mean the 2nd variant which is `struct file *fdata_val;`. And for that part you have to allocate memory.

The following example is for 2 files which will also answer your question about how to refer to the data:

```
// Set variables and allocate space for 2 file structures
message response;
u_int no_files      = 2;
u_int file_size     = 1024;
u_int last_mod_time = 42;
response.message_u.fdata.fdata_len = no_files;
response.message_u.fdata.fdata_val = malloc(no_files * sizeof(struct file));

// Access 1st file and allocate space for file content
response.message_u.fdata.fdata_val[0].last_mod_time         = last_modification;
response.message_u.fdata.fdata_val[0].contents.contents_len = file_size;
response.message_u.fdata.fdata_val[0].contents.contents_val = malloc(file_size * sizeof(char));

// Access 2nd file and allocate space for file content
response.message_u.fdata.fdata_val[1].last_mod_time         = last_modification;
response.message_u.fdata.fdata_val[1].contents.contents_len = file_size;
response.message_u.fdata.fdata_val[1].contents.contents_val = malloc(file_size * sizeof(char));
```

---

To learn more about the relationship between the XDR specification language and the generated C output this answer on SO: [Understanding XDR specification to create a *.x file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26625494/8051589) is helpful.

Further there is a nice book [*Power Programming with RPC by John Bloomer*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0937175773), it's quite old (1991) but the Remote Procedure Call protocol is it too. This book is about the RPC protocol that uses the XDR for sending/receiving data. The XDR language (using rpcgen, filter functions, etc.) is very well described in that book.

> Below are some XDR specifications:
>
> [image: xdr specification language taken from link provided above]

Comment: @JoannaM: Does this answer helped you? Do you have more questions?

Comment: Yes, it did!. Thank you. I appreciate you taking your time. I really needed to check as, you said, the .h generated file and also read a little bit more about  xdr. The post you suggested also helped a lot.

Comment: @JoannaM: I've added a link to a book in my answer that I think is good for diving into XDR: [Power Programming with RPC by John Bloomer](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0937175773/?tag=stackoverfl08-20).